# Show that there is one and only one homomorphism such that the tensor product diagram commutes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, ring-homomorphism

*Proposition* Let $M_1,...,M_n$ de modules over a commutative ring $R$. If $(P,p)$ is a tensor product of $M_1,...,M_n$, then, for every multilinear function $q:M_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times M_n\to Q$, there is one and **only one** homomorphism $h:P\to Q$ such that $q=h(p)$.

From the definition of tensor product, we know there is such homomorphism $h$.

I'm having a hard time proving its uniqueness. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: From the proof of existence of tensor products, one can see that the collection of all "pure-tensors"(i.e the image of $p$) form a spanning set for the entire tensor product. So the map $h$ is determined by its values on such pure-tensors. But now the equation $q=h\circ p$ tells us exactly that the value of $h$ is known on pure-tensors.

Comment: What is your definition of tensor product?  The most common definition includes the uniqueness you are asking about as part of the definition...

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I believe it should be in the definition as well. My definition only states that, for evey miltulinear function, such a homomorphism exists.

Comment: Can you write out the definition you are using in full? (Edit it into the question.)  It may have some little detail that is not normally included which implies the uniqueness.